# trying to compare some data to check pricing over multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vlookup

Column A has product code and column D has the sales price, both are in sheet 1. In sheet 2, product code is in column A and Sales price is in Column H.

I'm looking for excel to use the product code that is in sheet1 column A and find it in sheet 2 and also compare the price that is in sheet 1 column D to sheet 2 column H.

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide some example column data, along with your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$H$4,8,FALSE),"")
```

**Sheet 1:**

[image]

**Sheet 2:**

[image]

**Edited Answer:**

Use the below firmula in sheet 1 column E.

```
=IF(D2<>IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$H$4,8,FALSE),""),"Changed","Not Changed")
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: thanks ! was close but not quite. I need it to show the new price... so sheet 1 has the old price and sheet 2 has the new price and want to be able to see if it has changed. got 50,000 lines to add this to :(

Comment: You can see edited answer. use the formula in Sheet 1 column E and then filter out

Comment: sheet 1 A: 002.0058 B: BINZEL MB15 RETAIN SPRING  C:0.5100  E: Changed

Comment: Sheet 2:  A 002.0058 B: BINZEL MB15 RETAIN SPRING C: 0.51

Comment: I'm finding that colum A may not match in both sheets so how can I change it to search the whole colum in sheet 2 and match the prices up ?